# Разбираюсь сейчас с git. Вопрос про работу с удаленным репозиторием с разных компьютеров. Почему могу пушить в чужой репозиторий без ограничений

Tags: git, github

1. Зашел с "компьютера1" в гитхаб под "аккаунтом1" создал репозиторий.
2. Зашел с "компьютера2" в гитхаб под "аккаунтом2" скопировал ссылку на репозиторий, который создал в первом шаге.
3. На "компьютере2" сделал git clone "скопированная ссылка"
4. На "компьютере2" создал некий файл в склонированном репозитории file.txt с неким содержанием.
5. На "компьютере2" сделал git add -A далее git commit -m Commit
6. На "компьютере2" сделал git push origin main

И все без проблем запушилось в удаленный репозиторий "аккаунта1" из первого шага. Без каких либо препятствий, пуллреквестов. Почему так происходит? Получается любой рандомный человек может склонировать мой репозиторий и запушить свои изменения в мой репозиторий в гитхабе без моего ведома??

Comment: А вы уверены, что аккаунт1 и аккаунт2 это разные аккаунты? Если таки разные, вы уверены, что аккаунт1 не предоставлял доступ аккаунту2?

Comment: @andreymal аккаунт1 это давно созданный аккаунт, мой основной, а аккаунт 2 вот прям только-что создал, так что доступ вряд ли есть

Comment: А вы уверены, что на компьютере2 подключен именно аккаунт2?

Comment: @andreymal  не уверен, ибо не знаю как к гиту на компьютере привязывается аккаунт, но user.name и user.email указаны от аккаунта2, точно не от аккаунта1. но эти настройки они же только для коммитов, никакой привязки аккаунта гитхаба к гиту они не делают вроде, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Тогда почитайте в какой-нибудь документации как привязывается https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/faqs/git-auth

Comment: Покажите репозиторий.

Comment: Какой протокол используется для клонирования?

Comment: верится с трудом.  дайте ссылку на свою репу, мы тоже туда что-нибудь запушим )))

Comment: я проверил на другом компьютере, действительно нельзя запушить, видимо на компьютере2 как-то хранятся учетные данные, только я пока не понял, как и  где, спасибо за ответы

Comment: протокол  HTTPS, репозиторий https://github.com/NikolayBaskakov/Bulletin_Board , это к ответам на комментарии